# Qual è il significato di "riversare" in questa frase?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Ho letto la spiegazione sul Canto XXVII dell'*Inferno* della *Commedia* di Dante Alighieri che si trova su [questo sito web](http://imalpensanti.it/2014/12/28/divina-domenica-inferno-canto-27/). A un certo punto si può leggere la frase seguente:

> Il dannato ha riconosciuto la lingua di Virgilio, ed insiste affinché non gli venga negato un colloquio, vista soprattutto l’atroce condizione in cui **riversa**.

Fa riferimento a queste parole pronunciate dall'anima di Guido da Montefeltro, il dannato della frase sopra citata, che è intrappolata dentro una fiamma, nello stesso modo in cui si presenta Ulisse nel celebre canto precedente:

> udimmo dire: «O tu a cu’ io drizzo 
>   la voce e che parlavi mo lombardo, 
>   dicendo “Istra ten va, più non t’adizzo”,   
>   perch’io sia giunto forse alquanto tardo, 
>   non t’incresca restare a parlar meco; 
>   vedi che non incresce a me, e ardo!    
>   Se tu pur mo in questo mondo cieco 
>   caduto se’ di quella dolce terra 
>   latina ond’io mia colpa tutta reco,    
>   dimmi se Romagnuoli han pace o guerra; 
>   ch’io fui d’i monti là intra Orbino 
>   e ’l giogo di che Tever si diserra».

La mia domanda è sul significato del verbo "riversare" nella frase sopra citata. Ho cercato questo verbo in alcuni dizionari, ma non riesco a vedere a quale accezione corrisponda l'uso che se ne fa in questo testo (che però non ho difficoltà a capire in modo globale perché ho letto il Canto XXVII con i commenti di Bianca Garavelli in un libro). Sapreste spiegarmelo?

Comment: Da un'occhiata rapida alla pagina web non capisco chi è l'autore. Effettivamente sembra una svista per “versa”, che come spiega @abarisone è il verbo che uno normalmente userebbe in questo contesto.

Comment: @DaG: Proveniva da un sito web chiamato "Freemaninrealworld" che, non so perché, è sparito. Ma non ricordo chi fosse l'autore (forse non l'ho mai saputo).

Comment: @DaG: Ah, ho appena visto che il nome dell'autore appare giusto sotto il titolo "Divina Domenica – Inferno – Canto XXVII": [Simone Germini](http://imalpensanti.it/author/simone-germini/).

Comment: Grazie, @Charo!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oggi si direbbe:

> L’atroce condizione in cui **versa**

Infatti Treccani per [versare](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/versare2/) riporta:

> **versare**[2] v. intr. [dal lat. *versari*, forma mediale di *versare* (v. la
>   voce prec.), propr. «muoversi, aggirarsi in un luogo», e quindi
>   «trovarsi», ecc.] (*io vèrso*, ecc.; aus. *avere* e anche *essere*). –
>   Essere, trovarsi in una determinata condizione o situazione: *v. nella
>   più squallida miseria, in tristissime condizioni, in fin di vita.* In
>   usi ant. o letter., essere, vivere in un determinato luogo: *non può
>   intendersi che una favella spieghi cose astratte per termini pur’
>   astratti, se non se ella sia di nazione, nella quale molto e lungo
>   tempo sieno versati filosofi* (Vico).

Comment: Si può dire sia “in cui si trova” o “in cui si ritrova” (con leggerissima sfumatura di significato). Lo stesso potrebbe applicarsi a “in cui versa” e “in cui riversa”. Vezzo dell'autore, forse.

Comment: @egreg: "Riversare" nel senso di "versare di nuovo"? Cioè, volendo in certo senso indicare che si trovava in una situazione nuova (una situazione insolita e inaspettata) rispetto a quella della sua vita precedente?

Comment: @Charo No, “ritrova” in quel senso ha un prefisso *intensivo* e non *ripetitivo*. Come in “mi ritrovai per una selva oscura”, dove Dante non era *mai* stato prima.

Comment: @egreg: Volevo dire "di nuovo" come una cosa nuova, non come una ripetizione. Non mi sono espressa bene.